# Separating elements in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I have a vector of structure A in the device memory of GPU.

```
struct A{
    int a;
    int type;
}
```

I am trying to split each type and store it in an array.

```
For example if the types are 0,1 and 2,then split all 0's,1's and 2's 
in a separate array.
```

The approach I am thinking is to implement it using switch case in parallel but it might lead to a lot of divergence and thus may not be an efficient.

Is there any other approach that would help ?

Comment: How would you do it in C/C++?  If you provide some sample code, it will help to clarify things, and answer questions about desired vector lengths, packing arrangement, etc.  Or provide a sample vector and show the desired result vectors.

Comment: I assume it is the splitting you're hoping to do in parallel?  Do you know beforehand how many of each type there are?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes,I am trying to to it in parallel. The different types are known beforehand. Will mapping it to a type of bucket sort will help ?

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking.  Each thread has a "local buckets" and works through its own chunk of the list (putting each item into the appropriate local bucket).  Then you just have to carefully implement how to join the buckets.  There may already exist such a thing with the thrust libraries (not certain).  I know the thrust libraries implement a parallel reduce function (for summing vectors, for example), it may be abstracted enough to combine "buckets."

Comment: What you are looking for is called stream compaction.

Comment: Are you trying to re-order the data based on the type? Is it like a once off raddix sort?

Comment: @ChristianSarofeen  yes, im trying to reorder based on the type. I am trying to implement it as a variant of bucket sort and trying to separate each type in a different bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking out thrust:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/

[how fast is thrust::sort and what is the fastest radix sort implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854838/how-fast-is-thrustsort-and-what-is-the-fastest-radix-sort-implementation)

There is a way to sort with key/value pairs in case you need something else to be sorted along with it:

[Thrust Sort by key on the fly or different approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632649/thrust-sort-by-key-on-the-fly-or-different-approach)

I have implemented my own cuda radix sort. I needed to keep track of an index number while I sorted on something specific. If these options don't work for you I can try to find some time to document it.